# Newly created Content Type not showing up

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I created a new Content Type in our Drupal 6 install but it does not show up in the "Create Content" list. I created the new content type as admin and am viewing the Create Content list as admin, too.

Can somebody help me figure out why it isn't showing?

**Update**
After troubleshooting this with a co-worker, we are pinning it on the Drupal install. I was told to put this on the back-burner for now. Maybe if I can come back to it I can post a solution. Thanks for the answers, but permissions don't seem to be the issue here. Our Drupal install pre-dates any of the web employees at my office and we have to put our efforts into other projects for now.

Answer (score 2):

You may still have to give your role permission to the newly created content type before you can use it.  Check the permissions for the new content type and your role.

Comment: I did this under the new content type's "Access Control" tab. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @letseatfood check under /admin/user/permissions.  This is typically where the permissions are set.  But if you have a module that provide additional access control over your content types, then my solution may not apply.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to "rebuild permissions" under the content menu.